# Fill colour of google maps polygon is not displayed

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have encountered some strange issue and have no idea how to deal with it. So I am using google maps to display sam area. I placed some polygons there and i want to set a proper colour of them. In most cases it is working pretty well and polygons fill colour is set as I wish, but sometimes my polygon stays blank and, after i zoom in or out map, the colour is displayed correctly. Have you seen a similar issue, and have an idea how to solve/fix it?

I set the colours using for loop and setting the polygons `fillColor` as it is shown below

`polygons.forEach {
                it.isVisible = true
                it.fillColor = color
        }`

Any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: don't know how the maps api works but that sounds like there is a missing refresh / redraw / ? call

Comment: I tried to call `invalidate()` method on my mapView but it has no result

Comment: Probably polygon has self-intersections.

Comment: No, it is just square, but if it were polygon with self-intersections why sth like that can happen?

Comment: Could you paste how exactly you initialize `color`?

Comment: @Szuler Take a look at [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/257).